# Как правильно использовать RSA с электронной подписью с хешированием?

Tags: криптография, rsa, цифровая-подпись

Я пытаюсь понять алгоритм [**RSA**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) для [**цифровой подписи**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C). Следую такой схеме:

> **Подпись**:
>
> 1. Взять открытый текст ***m***
> 2. Создать цифровую подпись ***s*** с помощью своего секретного ключа ***[d,n]***: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
> 3. Передать пару  ***[m,s]***, состоящую из сообщения и подписи.
>
> **Верификация/проверка**:
>
> 1. Принять пару ***[m,s]***
> 2. Взять открытый ключ ***[e,n]***
> 3. Вычислить прообраз сообщения из подписи:
>
>    [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
> 4. Проверить подлинность подписи (и неизменность сообщения), сравнив ***m*** и ***m'***
>
> *Источник: [Цифровая подпись с RSA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#.D0.A6.D0.B8.D1.84.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.8C)*

---

Но я также хотел использовать [**хеширование**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Собираюсь подписывать не сообщение, а его «хеш-образ»: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Алгоритм подписи возможно изменится таким образом:

**Подпись**:

1. Взять открытый текст ***m***
2. Сгенерировать хэш сообщения: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Создать цифровую подпись ***s*** с помощью своего секретного ключа ***[d,n]***: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Передать пару  ***[m,s]***, состоящую из сообщения и подписи.

**Верификация/проверка**:

1. Принять пару ***[m,s]***
2. Взять открытый ключ ***[e,n]***
3. Вычислить прообраз сообщения из подписи: 
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Проверить подлинность подписи (и неизменность сообщения), сравнив ***m*** и ***m'*** ???

До использования хеширования мы могли проверить подлинность подписи (и неизменность сообщения), сравнив ***m*** и ***m'***. Но сейчас после 3-го шага мы получим ***m'*** в хешированном виде (не изначальный текст). Ведь невозможно сравнить оригинальное сообщение ***m*** и и хешированную версию ***m'*** (учитывая что хеширование необратимо и нельзя по хешу восстановить сообщение). Как поступить в такой ситуации?

---

**Мой вопрос:** Каков правильный алгоритм RSA с электронной подписью с хешированием?

Comment: При проверке вы получаете как само сообщение, так и его подпись. Выполняете хеширование сообщения как и в момент подписи и сверяете полученный хеш с пришедшим, подписанным

Comment: Для проверки используйте два значения: первый просто хэш, второй подписанный хэш (то есть вы подписываете копию созданного первого хэша), затем где это необходимо, подписанный хэш Вы расшифровываете с помощью открытого ключа (публичного ключа) и сравниваете два хэша если они равны значит все ок.